# Stop Current Password can't be blank issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4. I'm trying to send a hidden field to my controller, and if the hidden field is set to true, then I want to delete an attribute. Right now, my form looks like:

```
<input name="store[_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false" />
<input type='text' name="store[name]">
```

I have some jQuery that sets the hidden field to true if a button is clicked. So basically, if someone clicks a "Remove Store Name" button, I want to send the hidden field with a value of true, and delete store[name] from inserting to the database.

My controller right now looks like:

```
def create
   @store = Store.new(store_params)

   if params[:_destroy] == true
      params.delete :name
   end

   respond_to do |format|
      if @store.save
      ...
```

But I get a `unknown attribute: _destroy` with my current code.

Comment: The purpose of this `params[:store][:_destroy]` is to be able to destroy records, not to empty another attribute of the record. Use jQuery to empty/disable the text input for the name instead, right before submitting the form.

Comment: @MrYoshiji, Ah I see, that makes much more sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use jQuery to disable the input when clicking on the "Remove store name" button:

```
f.input :name, id: :store_name

link_to 'Remove Store Name', '#', onclick: "$('form input#store_name').prop('disabled', !$('form input#store_name').prop('disabled'));return false;"
```

The longer version:

```
f.input :name, id: :store_name

link_to 'Remove Store Name', '#', onclick: 'handle_remove_store_name(); return false;'

# javascript
window.handle_remove_store_name = function() {
  var current_disabled_state = $('form input#store_name').prop('disabled');
  $('form input#store_name').prop('disabled', !current_disable_state);
}
```

A disabled input will not be included in the params submitted via the form.